# creating a class in python - error

Tags: python, class, queue, append

The program I am creating should run a queue class however errors occur that append is not able to be used in the class as it does not exist, even thought it is set to a string. Could someone help me understand why I am receiving these errors?

```
class Queue:

    def queue(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.out_stack = []

    def enqueue(self, other='string'):
        self.enqeue = self.queue.append(other)

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.out_stack:
            while self.queue:
                self.dequeue = self.out_stack.append(self.queue.pop(1))
        return self.dequeue

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.queue == []
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create an instance variable `self.queue`, you are shadowing the method defined by `def queue(self):`

It looks like that method should perhaps be your `__init__` method

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.out_stack = []

    def enqueue(self, other='string'):
        self.queue.append(other)

    def dequeue(self):               # what is this method supposed to do?
        if not self.out_stack:
            while self.queue:
                self.dequeue = self.out_stack.append(self.queue.pop(1))
        return self.dequeue

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.queue == []
```

Now there is still a similar problem with `self.dequeue` being used as both a method and an attribute. I am not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize got rid of dequeue as an attribute program is working